# mysqli_query() returns "Table doesn't exist" for known table - Permissions issue?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here's my code:

```
$dsn = "dbinstancename.c5twsfnt9pph.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$port = "3306";
$db = "mysql";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$sourcetable = "test";

//initialize the connection
$link = mysqli_connect($dsn, $username, $password, $db, $port);

if ($link->connect_error){

        echo "Connection Failed";

        }

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(mysqli_select_db($link, $db)){
        echo 'connected successfully';
}

//set initial source id to import from
$sourceid = "1";

// get the first source url and name
$query = "SELECT * FROM $sourcetable WHERE id = $sourceid;";
//echo $query;

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if($result === FALSE) {
        echo "query failed";
        echo mysqli_error($link);

}else{
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo $row['name'];
                echo $row['url'];
        }
}

//echo "finished";

?>
```

The issue is that the table test does exist and contains data. The test table is in the database mysql.

If I change the value of database I am given an error that it cannot connect (even for other known databases beside mysql).

When this program runs the output is "connected successfullyquery failedTable 'mysql.test' doesn't exist"

Any help would be hugely appreciated. This an AWS RDS instance running mariadb, and the PHP is running from an EC2 micro instance.

EDIT: Here is the mysql string to prove table exists:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [mysql]> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| column_stats              |
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| gtid_slave_pos            |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| index_stats               |
| innodb_index_stats        |
| innodb_table_stats        |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| roles_mapping             |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| table_stats               |
| tables_priv               |
| test                      |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
31 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]> select * from test;
+----+--------+------------+
| id | name   | url        |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | banana | banana.com |
+----+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You do have a database named mysql that contains a table named test?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thanks for your reply. Please see my edits; I think I do!

Comment: sorry, do you use the same user to connect and connect from the same client ? the permission can be different for each Host / IP for the same user . It looks like that you dont have the right permissions, and also your error message is like this. if you cant connect to the database

Comment: Check the permission for user, password and host combination. Looks like your user is not authorized to display that table. You may need to grant it the right authorizations on that table

Comment: Thanks @LelioFaieta and Bernd 

Any thoughts on how to do that via AWS? I had called them earlier but they were unable to provide any insight.. 

The user has full permissions as far as I know and I can't figure out how to verify whether they do.

Comment: I have moved this thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260390/how-to-edit-user-permissions-for-aws-rds and will post further information if I determine the true solution.

Comment: Do not put your tables into the `mysql` database; that database is used only for system purposes.  Instead, `CREATE DATABASE somename` to have your own database to work in.

Comment: Good thought - Thanks @RickJames