# How to edit user permissions for AWS RDS

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

My previous post here ([mysqli_query() returns "Table doesn't exist" for known table - Permissions issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35259409/mysqli-query-returns-table-doesnt-exist-for-known-table-permissions-issue)) explains the details of how I arrived at this issue.

I am now convinced that the username and password which I set while creating my DB instance have not been given the appropriate permissions to allow me to edit the contents of the my own database.

This is extremely frustrating, so if anyone has any tips or tricks on how to modify these permissions I would really appreciate it.

To clarify, currently all permissions are set via the EC2 Security Groups, and as a result I cannot actually even see the username and password I created when I made the database, so it doesn't appear that I can set the permissions any differently, or edit the policies.

Thanks a bunch.

Alex

Comment: *I cannot actually even see the username and password I created when I made the database* ... you can't see it **where**?  "All" permissions are *not* set by security groups -- only the ability to connect to the server (at all) is controlled by security groups.

Answer (score 0):

So I went back to your previous question to see what you were doing. The database named mysql is a system database. Not a very good place to create tables. In fact the permissions for this database are likely restricted as it can break mysql and/or the RDS automation.

You need to create a new database for your tables. While you do not get super user access within RDS, you do get full access to any databases that you set up. System databases are going to be restricted.

Security groups manage connectivity to RDS. Its the same thing as an external firewall.

Grants manage permissions within MySQL. The MySQL manual will explain how you can use these.

Comment: Thanks @datasage 
I realized my error was actually just in the way I was accessing the RDS instance. Because I had mysql installed on my instance, I was receiving a confirmation from my localhost that I was connected to that database, however if I wanted to access my RDS the process is quite different as explained here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

I hope this helps someone in the future. I did not find much documentation to lead me to this, and kind of ended up trial and erroring it until I found this link. Sucks that ec2->rds is remote...